# Building an Android Chat App with Pusher: Not Working

Tags: android, node.js, chat, pusher

Following this tutorial: https://blog.pusher.com/build-an-android-chat-app-with-pusher/ , I have been debugging for hours  to find out why it is not working.

From the client I do the following:

```
private void postMessage()  {

    String text = messageInput.getText().toString();

    // return if the text is blank
    if (text.equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

    // set our JSON object
    params.put("text", text);
    params.put("name", "DogLover69");
    params.put("time", new Date().getTime());

    // create our HTTP client
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post(MESSAGES_ENDPOINT, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    messageInput.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Something went wrong :(",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Note: MESSAGES_ENDPOINT is the ip address of the server + the port I'm connecting to, and I have confirmed it is correct.

From the server I do the following:

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');

var pusher = new Pusher({
  appId: "421748",
  key: "4e789b8f7019463f945b",
  secret: "fff93ef698f9231c00dd"
});


...


app.post('/messages', function(req, res){
var message = {
  text: req.body.text,
  name: req.body.name
}
console.log(message);
pusher.trigger('messages', 'new_message', message, function(err){
        console.log("bananas");
        done(err);
    });
res.json({success: 200});
});
```

The server prints the messages correctly and responds with the 200 success code; however, **although the server successfully receives the message from the client, the server cannot send the message to pusher**. Using the debug console on the pusher website confirms this.

This is triggering the error, so I believe it is the issue:

```
pusher.trigger('messages', 'new_message', message, function(err){
    console.log("bananas");
    done(err);
});
```

[Server output when I catch the error from pusher.trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJz0c.png)

I have been trying to figure out whats wrong for a very long time now,
any help would be appreciated. I may try to get in touch with the pusher folks as I have followed the tutorial religiously and triple checked all my steps. There isn't a lot of resources for my particular issue but I have hope others with this issue can find this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct. Can you please double check if there's a `cluster` value associated with it - you should be able to see it on dashboard.pusher.com.